# GRASS r.grow doesn't seem to change raster values at all

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have a raster map in GRASS that looks like this:

[image: Raster map with binary values]

The red cells have a value of 1, the yellow cells have a value of 0.

I am trying to use the `r.grow` command to 'fill in' the gaps in the red lines, but it seems that whatever options I give the command, the output is either exactly the same as the input, or entirely 1, or entirely 0.

The way to run the command that seems most sensible is:

```
r.grow input=extracted@PERMANENT output=gr8 radius=3.01
```

which, as far as I can tell, should grow all positive cells by 3 cells. However, it doesn't seem to do anything at all - the output map is exactly the same as the input map. Changing the `old` and `new` values doesn't seem to change it either.

Am I doing something wrong here? I have read through the manual page for the `r.grow` command many times, but can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you mean that the yellow has a value of *zero* or that it is *null*? The [manual page](http://grass.unibuc.ro/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.grow.html) says that the non-null cells are expanded only into the *null* cells (which, by default, apparently are encoded with the value -1, not zero).

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to solve it. I didn't notice that it was talking about *NULL* pixels, rather than *0* pixels (or maybe I was just used to `grow` functions working with {0,1} rasters rather than {NULL,1} rasters. If you add this as an answer then I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, you can use the r.null command to set zero values to NULL: r.null <rast_map> setnull=0

Comment: (+1 for the question.) I have converted the comment into a formal answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page says that the non-null cells are expanded only into the null cells (which, by default, apparently are encoded with the value -1, not zero).

In a comment, @Micha states you can use `r.null` to convert the zero values to nulls, as in

```
 r.null <rast_map> setnull=0
```

After you make such a change, `r.grow` should produce the expected output.